# getBoundingClientRect return zero for angular directive at run time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I wrote an angular directive to track each paragraph in a huge content. When the content is static in the page it works fine. When the content is served by API, getBoundingClientRect always return zero for my placeholders. I do recompile before giving it to view. How to calculate getBoundingClientRect for a directive inside dynamic content ?

My Content:

```
<p storytracker="261">"He don't look to have taken much harm." said Mrs. White politely.</p>
```

In my Diective:

```
  angular.module('web')
    .directive('storyTracker', storyTracker);

  function storyTracker($compile) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        sid: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        //Check if element is in viewport on page load
        if (isElementInViewport(elem[0])) {
           //Element is in view port
        }

        //Check if element is in viewport on page scroll
        var page = angular.element(window);
        page.bind('scroll', function() {
          if (isElementInViewport(elem[0])) {
            //Element is in view port
          }
        });
      }
    };
    return directive;
  }

      function ifElementinviewport(el) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
          rect.top >= 0 &&
          rect.left >= 0 &&
          rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
          rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );
      }
```

Comment: Please provide code for entire directive, best if you can provide some jsfiddle that reproduces this bug.

Comment: in which part of the directive code you're doing this ```ifElementinviewport``` measurement? if it's in link function, then indeed element may be still not in the DOM => 0px size

Comment: @shershen Yes, added the entire directive code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with $compile. I was compiling the API response ( with storytracker directive ) and binding it via **ng-bind-html**, the directive were triggered during $compile not during render. Now, I have changed it to **append**. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try a couple of things:

--Push the method call in a timeout wrapper

```
$timeout( ifElementinviewport, 0 ).then( function(isElementInViewPortFlag) {
    //if condition checking
});
```

This will wait till the rendering engine has completed execution which might resolve your issue.

Also you can try wrapping the execution in the "ready" wrapper, such as :

```
angular.element(elem).ready(function () {
   //elem is the div which holds the dynamic content
});
```

--If this also dosen't work , then you will have to get a callback from the service which loads the content and perform the operation post that.